# How to make a smooth projectile in roblox?

Tags: lua, lag, roblox

I am trying to make a projectile (Energy ball) for my game. I am using body velocities, but the issue is is that it seems laggy. I shoot it then half a second through flight it seems to stop in mid air for a quarter of a second then continue. This only happens the first minute of playing.
I tested shooting at the ground so at an angle so it will go slower, but it seems the the ball freezes when it reaches a certain distance from the player, not a certain time.

The actual projectile is a less transparent ball inside of a bigger, more transparent ball, connected by a weld. If I remove one of the balls so the projectile is just one ball, my issue is gone. How can I remove the issue while keeping both balls?

Here is my code that I tried:

```
EnergyBallEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player, MouseClickLocation)
    local Character = Player.Character
    local Humanoid = Character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if Humanoid.Health > 0 and not DisabledItems[Player.UserId..'EnergyBall'] then
        DisabledItems[Player.UserId..'EnergyBall'] = true
        Humanoid:LoadAnimation(script.EnergyBallAnimation):Play()
        local Ball = Instance.new("Part", SpellsFolder)
        local CasterValue = Instance.new("ObjectValue", Ball)
        CasterValue.Name = "Caster"
        CasterValue.Value = Player.Character
        Ball:SetNetworkOwner(nil) --removing or modifying this
        Ball.Transparency = 1
        Ball.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        Ball.BrickColor = BrickColor.new(0, 255, 255)
        Ball.Material = Enum.Material.Neon
        Ball.Size = Vector3.new(2.2, 2.2, 2.2)
        Ball.Massless = true
        Ball.CanCollide = false
        local Weld = Instance.new("Weld", Ball)
        Weld.Part0 = Ball
        Ball = Instance.new("Part", Ball)
        Ball:SetNetworkOwner(nil) --or this have no effect that is visible
        Ball.Transparency = 1
        Ball.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        Ball.BrickColor = BrickColor.new(0, 255, 255)
        Ball.Material = Enum.Material.Neon
        Ball.Size = Vector3.new(1.6, 1.6, 1.6)
        Ball.Massless = true
        Weld.Part1 = Ball
        Weld = Instance.new("Weld", Ball)
        Weld.Part0 = Ball
        if Character:FindFirstChild("LeftHand") then
            Weld.Part1 = Character.LeftHand
        else

        end
        for i = 0, 40, 1 do
            Ball.Transparency = Ball.Transparency - 0.012
            Ball.Parent.Transparency = Ball.Parent.Transparency - 0.006
            wait(0.02)
        end
        Weld:Destroy()
        local Motion = Instance.new("BodyVelocity", Ball)
        Motion.Velocity = ((MouseClickLocation - Player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position).Unit*100)
        DisabledItems[Player.UserId..'EnergyBall'] = nil
    end
end)
```

Here is some more code I tried:

```
EnergyBallEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player, MouseClickLocation)
    local Character = Player.Character
    local Humanoid = Character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if Humanoid.Health > 0 and not DisabledItems[Player.UserId..'EnergyBall'] then
        DisabledItems[Player.UserId..'EnergyBall'] = true
        Humanoid:LoadAnimation(script.EnergyBallAnimation):Play()
        local Model = Instance.new("Model", SpellsFolder)
        local Ball = Instance.new("Part", Model)
        local CasterValue = Instance.new("ObjectValue", Model)
        CasterValue.Name = "Caster"
        CasterValue.Value = Player.Character
        Ball.Transparency = 1
        Ball.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        Ball.BrickColor = BrickColor.new(0, 255, 255)
        Ball.Material = Enum.Material.Neon
        Ball.Size = Vector3.new(2.2, 2.2, 2.2)
        Ball.Massless = true
        Ball.CanCollide = false
        local Weld = Instance.new("Weld", Ball)
        Weld.Part0 = Ball
        local Ball2 = Instance.new("Part", Model)
        Model.PrimaryPart = Ball2
        Ball2:SetNetworkOwner(nil)
        Ball2.Transparency = 1
        Ball2.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
        Ball2.BrickColor = BrickColor.new(0, 255, 255)
        Ball2.Material = Enum.Material.Neon
        Ball2.Size = Vector3.new(1.6, 1.6, 1.6)
        Ball2.Massless = true
        Weld.Part1 = Ball2
        Weld = Instance.new("Weld", Ball2)
        Weld.Part0 = Ball2
        if Character:FindFirstChild("LeftHand") then
            Weld.Part1 = Character.LeftHand
        else

        end
        for i = 0, 40, 1 do
            Ball2.Transparency = Ball2.Transparency - 0.012
            Ball.Transparency = Ball.Transparency - 0.006
            wait(0.02)
        end
        Weld:Destroy()
        local Motion = Instance.new("BodyVelocity", Ball)
        Motion.Velocity = ((MouseClickLocation - Player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position).Unit*100)
        DisabledItems[Player.UserId..'EnergyBall'] = nil
    end
end)
```

I hate this behaviour and I NEED to fix it

Another observation is if I comment out the second ball creation and stuff so it is a just one ball, the bug is gone

Comment: Are you using unions? Unions are very laggy and not recommended.

Comment: I also had some problems with projectiles, in the end setting network ownership did not really help. I switched to FastCast module, Consider switching, it does not really require a lot of changes ... https://devforum.roblox.com/t/making-a-combat-game-with-ranged-weapons-fastcast-may-be-the-module-for-you/133474

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the propulsion code to the clientside script in an `OnClientEvent:Connect()` block, and make the serverscript instead have `Ball:SetNetworkOwner(Player)` and `EnergyBallEvent:FireClient(Ball)`. I'm OP but I might as well answer this question now since I figured it out long ago.